# Is Personalized Pagerank and PageRank with Priors the same thing?

Tags: jung, pagerank

I am using JUNG PageRankWithPriors in my project. It seems to me PageRankWithPriors and Personalized PageRank are the same thing, but I could not find authoritative statements that confirm it.

Are they the same? If not, what's difference?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr they are not the same.

First, PageRank can refer to one of two things: 
(1) the original algorithm from 1998 (that is, a way to assign scores to the nodes in a graph based on a random walk on a transformed version of the graph), or (2) the system of which the above algorithm is a part, which Google uses to rank web pages in response to a query.

If you're referring to (2), then there are many different ways to personalize search query responses, and listing them all is beyond the scope of this response.  :)

Even if you're referring to (1), though, PageRank with priors is only one way to personalize PageRank.  Others include a personalized weighting of edges, or filtering either the node or the edge sets, but there are quite a few more.

You may find the papers here of interest: http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/pagerank.shtml

Comment: Thank you Joshua, you answered most of my question! Then a small question I wonder if you may clarify it for me: the PageRank with Priors algorithm in paper "Algorithms for Estimating Relative Importance in Networks" by Scott White and Padhraic Smyth and the algorithm in section 3.1 of "Topic-Sensitive PageRank: A Context-Sensitive Ranking Algorithm for Web Search" by Haveliwala, both of which give priors to nodes, are essentially the same thing? Thank you!

Comment: The algorithm in section 3.1 of Haveliwala's paper is a special case of PageRank with priors, in that PRWP allows any distribution of weights over the nodes, while Haveliwala's distribution is uniform for all nodes associated with the topic.  (Smyth and White's paper does use that same distribution as an example, though.)  Also, of course, Haveliwala's algorithm in 3.1 is only part of his overall approach.

Comment: Thank you very much, Joshua :-)